# prove that if $a>1$ , then the limit of $\frac{a^n}{n}$ is $\infty$ as n goes to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

prove that if $a>1$ , then the limit of $\frac{a^n}{n}$ is $\infty$ as n goes to $\infty$

I was trying to use the binomial theorem to replace $a$ with $1+k$, but then that $n$ on the denominator became a problem, should I use a different term for the binomial expansion?

Comment: Use L'Hospital's rule

Answer (score 4):

Write $a=1+b$ where $b>0$.  Then $a^n=1+nb+{n\choose2}b^2+\cdots$.  So $a^n>b^2n(n-1)/2$.  Thus $\frac{a^n}n\geq b^2(n-1)/2$.

Comment: You also have $n\geq 3\to a^n/n>b^3 n^{-2}\binom {n}{3}=b^2(n-1)(n-2)/n$ so $a^n/n^2\to \infty$ (etc ).